# Matlab using fzero to find intersecting points

Tags: matlab

i face an issue using fzero to find the x value where both graphs meet. 
 Both sets of data are on the same figure. 
  Data set 1

```
z = sqrt(D.^2 + x.^2)
zcost = CS1*z;
landcost = C01*(L-x);
totcost = @(x) zcost + landcost;
figure(2)
plot(x,totcost(x),'k-');
```

Data set 2

```
C2sea = CS2*(1+0.5*alpha*ee*D)*(sqrt(x.^2+(1+ee.^2)*D.^2));
C2land = C02*(L-x);
C2cost = @(x) C2sea + C2land;
figure(2)  %figure 2
plot(x,C2cost(x),'r-');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your code since you did not include the value of D, CS1, etc.,  but you can do something like:

```
% Make up some arbitrary functions
x = linspace(0,10);
y1 = @(t) (t - 3).^2 + 10;
y2 = @(t) (t - 7).^2 + 15;

% Plot them
plot(x, y1(x) ,x, y2(x))
ylim([0 50])

% Define another function of the difference between y1 and y2
% this difference should be zero when the functions intersect
z = @(t) y1(t) - y2(t);
fzero(z, 5)
```

Which gives:

```
ans =

    5.6250
```